# Make Apache Ignore Domains on the Same Server (Ubuntu 9.10). How?

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu

I'm running Apache on Ubuntu 9.10.

**I want Apache to ignore certain domains on my server, and let other HTTP servers make full use of them.**

I've used **mod_proxy** and other Apache modules to configure the proxy/redirect to certain ports but sometimes that's too much work or doesn't work properly.

***Example:***

Server 00.00.000.000

domain1.com:80 - Apache

domain2.com:80 - Apache

domain3.com:80 - Webrick

domain4.com:80 - Jetty

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible. It would require multiple applications listening on the same port, and you don't know what domain the request is for before reading the HTTP request.

You need to configure one of your web servers to handle all the traffic and proxy or redirect to the other servers.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to add another IP address for your server? In that case, you could have Apache listen on one ip address, and your other HTTP server listen on the second ip address.